# How to calculate the probability of this normally distributed event?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve the following probability problem:

> The gross weekly sales at a certain restaurant is a normal random
>   variable with mean \$2200 and standard deviation \$230. What is the
>   probability that the total gross sales over the next 2 weeks exceeds
>   $5000?

Source: [here](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rosario/classes/081/100a-2a/100aHW7Soln.pdf)

Clearly, this problem is asking for the sum of two normal random variables. I am assuming that each week's earnings are independent of each other. It is well known that the sum of 2 independent normal distributions will be a normal distribution with the sum of their mean and variances. That means:

Let the earnings be $X$ in the first week and $Y$ in the second week.
$$
X \sim Norm(\mu,\sigma^2) \text{ and Y } \sim Norm(\mu,\sigma^2) \\
X + Y \sim Norm(\mu+\mu,\sigma^2+\sigma^2) = Norm(2\mu,2\sigma^2)
$$

Thus, we see that:

$$
X, Y \sim Norm(2200,230^2)
$$

Hence, the total earnings in 2 weeks would be:

$$
X + Y \sim Norm(2(2200),2(230^2))
$$

The suggested answer in the source states that:

$$
X + Y \sim Norm(4400,460)
$$

I do not agree with this even after looking at the intermediate steps. Am I misunderstanding something here? Could someone please advise me?

Comment: One problem in the answer of the paper is that a normal distribution is denoted as $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma)$. This is not usual.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. I scoured my textbook and the Internet for the definition of normal distribution before deciding to ask here as I am unsure of myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct.  The solution that you linked to states:

$$\sigma(X) = \sqrt{Var(X)} = \sqrt{Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)} = \sqrt{2\sigma^2} = \sqrt{2} \sigma = 2(230) = 460$$

where the author is calling the two weeks' sales $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Somehow in the second-to-last equality the author slipped and replaced $\sqrt{2}$ with $2$.

Comment: Thanks! It really left me puzzled. I am bad at probability but looking at that answer really put me in doubt.